# Read ALL SMS in inbox or Send it to Server in React NATIVE

Tags: android, ios, react-native, sms, read-sms

I am building an app that requires the functionality of reading SMS from the inbox. It's a kind of app that Microsoft built known as SMS organizer. I'm trying to build it for the local crowd and I'm using react-native to do the same. I read many libraries but none seem to be helpful or informative for my cause.

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-read-sms
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-get-sms-android

Anyone has any idea for how I can accomplish the same.
PS- I'm aiming to do it for both androids as well as ios.

Comment: You definitely can't do it for iOS. Apps are not allowed to read messages as it would be a privacy violation.

Comment: @Paulw11 What if, I declare it before asking for permissions from the user. In our app, the first thing is the declaration stating the SMS permission for usage by the app.

Comment: In iOS there is no permission to request. You cannot ask for access to SMS messages. There is no way the user can give you permission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

True- We cannot read sms in IOS devices.

For Android, I found a library that helps to achieve this.

```
import SmsAndroid from 'react-native-get-sms-android'; 

var filter = {
  box: 'inbox',
};

const Readsms_list = async () => {
  SmsAndroid.list(
    JSON.stringify(filter),
    (fail) => {
      console.log('Failed with this error: ' + fail);
    },
    (count, smsList) => {
      console.log('Count: ', count);
      console.log('List: ', smsList);
      var arr = JSON.parse(smsList);

      arr.forEach(function (object) {
    // 'Object: ' +
    console.log(object);
    // console.log('-->' + object.date);
    // console.log('-->' + object.body);
  });
},
```

);
};

This helps in reading all the SMS from the device.